PWA does not reinstall
It appears that once a PWA (Progressive Web App) is installed, and then deleted, it can not be installed again.

On Android, clicking on Save to Home Screen shows an option to Install.
If this PWA is deleted from the home screen.
Clicking on Save to Home Screen no longer shows an option to Install.

I have tested this on Android S20 and S24. And also on iPhone 11.

I have restarted the phone.
The PWA does not appear in Settings-> Apps, so nothing can be deleted.

Is there a way to get around this?

Deleting an ordinary Android app from the home screen does no uninstall it. Look in the list of apps (swipe upwards on the home screen) and see if it is there?

The icons look like individual apps, but actually they are just additional links to your web browser. Which Webbrowser have you used for saving the PWA? This means only the web browser manages them. If nothing helps you can clear app data of the browser to reset/remove all saved links.

It turns out that a PWA has a manifest file called Manifest.json.  The tool that I was using did not update it so the links within were not pointing to valid resources.
And a line in the index.html file pointing to this manifest file got removed along the way.
I manually fixed the files after Googling to see what they were supposed to contain.  It had nothing to do with removal, the files just got mangled along the way.
